# Are "set on" and "determined to" interchangeable?

Tags: expressions, sentence-choice

They've been pretty set on pulling the plug for a while now, so I'm surprised nothing's happened yet.

They've been pretty determined to pull the plug for a while now, so I'm surprised nothing's happened yet.

- Are "set on" and "determined to" completely interchangeable here?
- Are they equally natural here?
- Which one would make the statement sound most bitter?

Comment: I have seen it only as "_dead set_ on [doing something]". (Which means: "super-duper determined".)

Answer (score 2):

If the question is rephrased as
Are "set on pulling" and "determined to pull" interchangeable?
then I would say mean the same thing, but "set on pulling" is much more informal.